# Using a cookie to show a Div for first time site visitors

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am attempting to show a div (`#home-landing`) on the home page of a site for the initial visit to the website. For all subsequent visits to the home page during the same session I would like `#home-landing` to be set to `display:none;`.

I found some code on stackoverflow for hiding a div after the first 5 visits of a visitor, but it is spread out across different sessions.

```
if (!$.cookie('visits')) {
  $.cookie('visits', 1, {
    expires: 30
  });
}
$.cookie('visits', (parseInt($.cookie('visits')) + 1), {
  expires: 30
})
//will expire after 30 days
var overlayContact = function () {
  if (parseInt($.cookie('visits')) < 5) {
    $('#home-landing').show();
  }
};
setTimeout(overlayContact, 180000);
});
```

How would I write the code so that this could be accomplished?

Comment: "*it is spread out across different sessions*," I bet you are using a single browser :)

Comment: @Alexander haha - no. I wish it was that simple. I run multiple browers on dev and I reset (clear cache, cookies, etc.) before testing.